Any Difference between `torch.distributions.normal.Normal` v.s. `torch.distributions.Normal`
I only see torch.distributions.normal.Normal in the official documents but never see torch.distributions.Normal. However, I sometimes see people use torch.distributions.Normal in their codes in Github. Could anyone explain if there is any difference between these two usages? Thanks a lot!
I'm confused why there is nothing about torch.distributions.Normal in the official document.
Official Document

They are the same thing. The pytorch distributions module imports all distributions to the distributions namespace for convenience. You can see the code here
